# Multiple HTTP form posts within 1 second

Tags: http, post

I'm seeing a very odd behavior where we are sometimes seeing 2 to 6 posts by a browser client from a web form within the same second. Because Apache logs only to the second I cannot tell exactly how quickly this happens. I DO know that it is NOT a case of users hitting back and re-submitting. Has anyone else experienced this? A few points:

1) it is not browser footprint specific (is happening with a few different browsers on different client platforms - Mac/PC)
2) it does not appear to be an issue with "load-balancing" or proxies

While our application is tolerant for this (ie it won't actually process the multiple posts) I'm concerned that this may indicate some sort of malware or the client's browser being compromised in some way. Any thoughts? I doubt it would help, but if someone thinks seeing the Apache log entries for a specific case would help, I can provide them.

TIA,

-Arne

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be causing this, such as a redirect that is not behaving as intended, or by client-side scripting that making unintended http requests, etc.  Are you able to reproduce this from your web browser?  If so, perhaps enabling the developer tools (by using F12 on IE or FF) to view HTTP headers being sent back and forth between the browser and the web server might shed some light on what is causing this.

Comment: This only occurs rarely (less than 2% of transactions) and has NEVER happened to me or anyone "within arms length". So unfortunately, as it's 1 in dozens, and these are random users, I have no way of looking at the headers.

Comment: Are you sure these are real users, and not bots?  Bots will tend to do this kind of thing.